# Unity load data from HTTP

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I created a game in unity that loads data from an HTTP request.
But when i build on the device, it stops on a splash screen and shows an error warning in the console:

> You are using download over http. Currently unity adds
>   NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to Info.plist to simplify transition, but it
>   will be removed soon. Please consider updating to https.

I use unity 5.x and Xcode 7.2.
Please help me resolve it!
Thanks!

Comment: Do as it says, use https not http.

Comment: What if the server doesn't provide the data over `https`?

Comment: Thanks, i resolve it!

Answer (score 0):

Open info.plist file from xCode and select Add row option by right click in info.plist file.

Select "App Transport Security Settings" option

"App Transport Security Settings" - Set it as dictionary - (it will set it automatically)

Then click on + icon and select Row "Allow Arbitrary Loads" and set it to YES.